# Apache httpd returns multiple values for CORS

Tags: apache, cors, httpd.conf

I am writing a web app that request data from another service I have deployed.
I have configured `Apache httpd` as a proxy to my web app.

```
...
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
...
```

Sending a request using `jquery`:

```
$ajax('https://service.com/path',{
  method: "POST",
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
})
```

I am sending a request with a token saved in the cookie.
The response I am getting is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://service.com/path`. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'https://myapp.com, *', but only one is allowed.
```

What have I configured wrong?

Comment: You have configured service.com 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header with multiple values.

Comment: I understood the error content, but I didn't configure it more than once. I suspect that it is something a bit more complex or it happened as a side effect from something else, because there is only 1 occurrence of the access-control-allow-origin and it contains only 1 value.

Comment: Those `Header always set` directives, are they from 'web app' apache, or from 'another service' apache?

Comment: The web app Apache, where the jquery request is coming from

Comment: The error is on  'another service' side, can you check the `Header set` there

Comment: Or at least it looks so :)

Comment: Already looked into that, there is no header settings there, straight up default configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127708/discussion-between-dusan-bajic-and-candroid).